# Remove trailing slash after .html extension

Tags: htaccess

my permalink settings are as follows:

sitename/%postname%.html

I have removed the trailing slash at the end.

I am also using a plugin called "Remove slug from custom post type" to remove the custom post type prefix in urls. This plugin adds in htaccess the following lines for each custom post type:

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1\.html [R=301,l]
RewriteRule ^POSTTYPENAME/(.+)/$ /$1\.html [R=301,l]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1\.html [R=301,l]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
```

So my issue is that each post, page, CPT page is accessible in two ways:
sitename/pagename.html
and
sitename/pagename.html/

There must be a syntax for redirecting urls with ".html/" at the end to just ".html", but so far I have managed only to break the site a couple of times.

I would greatly appreciate any help here.

Thanks